# Weird issue with inserting a complext object into the DB with EF CF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have an object containing 2 subobjects:
Customer - the parent object
Customer.Country - subobject.
The relationship is: 1Country - *Customers, so I don't want to create Country duplicates.
Now I want to create a new Customer object in the DB using EF.

**These are the ways I tried:**

1:

```
customer.Country = _context.Countries.Find(p => p.Id ==id);
var obj = _context.Customers.Create(customer);
return _context.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

2:

```
Context.Entry(customer.Country).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
Context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Added;
return Context.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

For some strange reason either way works only 1 or (maximum) 2 times! Then it pops up the error saying that subobject I'm trying to insert is already inserted...
That's weird, so I checked the states: the states of the subobjects were Unchanged, so I don't understand why it says that I am trying to insert the same object with the same keys.

**The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable.**

I am facing with this issue only when I use Code First. When I use .edmx I don't have this issue.

Comment: When you create referenced object, you need to assign its primary key. Otherwise EF will think it's a new object.

Comment: Please explain in more details what you mean

Comment: Like `var customer = new Customer { Country = new Country { Id = existingCountryId } } ` or `var customer = new Customer { CountryId = existingCountryId }` depending whether or not you have both foreign key, navigation property or both.

Comment: And you don't have to call `dbSet<T>.Create()` to create `T`, just `new T()` works well and is more readable.

Comment: Of course when I create a Country object(subobject) I always use the existing primary key. So I don't create a new Country object in the DB. I want to create only Customer object. And CustomerId is an auto increamented identity

Comment: How many connections do you have to the database?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532200/entity-framework-code-first-many-to-many-with-shared-elements

Answer (score 1):

The steps to create a new customer related to existing country should be:

If Customer has CountryId prop:

```
var newCust = new Customer
{
    CountryId = existingCountryId,
    ...
};
_context.Customers.Add(newCust);
```

Otherwise

```
var existingCountry = _context.Countries.Find(existingCountryId);
// or create an Country object with the corresponding Id and attach to the context

var newCust = new Customer
{
    Country = existingCountry,
    ...
};
_context.Customers.Add(newCust);
```

Comment: This is how I do and it works only 1 time. It seems to me that for some reason it thinks there is 1-1 relationship. I checked the DB - it's correct and I tested whether I can manually insert 1-* data and it works. But for some reason, now even the list of the Customers returns me only 1 record (since I updated each customer to only 1 country)

Comment: It's getting more and more weird: the Web  API shows that it returns me 3 customers, but on a client side json shows me only 1 customer and 2 more empty records...

Comment: Maybe you should show more code, I'm guessing what's happening. Also I wouldn't mix updating with querying, let's solve updating first checking against db and then let's work with queries.